# Can someone help me understand this roman numeral challenge?

Tags: ruby

```
def to_roman(num)
    values = [
        ["M",1000],
        ["CM",900],
        ["D",500],
        ["CD",400],
        ["C",100],
        ["XC",90],
        ["L",50],
        ["XL",40],
        ["X",10],
        ["IX",9],
        ["V",5],
        ["IV",4],
        ["I",1]
    ]
    roman = ""
    values.each do |set|
      letter = set[0]
      value = set[1]
      roman += letter * (num / value)
      num = num % value
    end 
    return roman
end
```

I'm completely lost here and would love some help.
What does the "roman += letter" counter do and why does it have to multiply the num/value
Why does the num divide value? 
What does that modulus do?

Comment: Use Inspect option `p`  or `puts` to print values and trace the program. You will understand it.  Example: `puts "Num: #{num}"` will print the value of num

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251521/how-to-convert-a-number-to-roman-numerals

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253896/2988#comment17104_253896

Answer (score 3):

As you're looping through, the program checks for the highest possible roman numeral you can use. When you're left with e.g. 345, the next highest possible numeral is `C`, which should be repeated `300/100 = 3` times. The number then 'becomes' 45, due to modulus, and you repeat to get 40, then 5, so 345 is 'translated' to CCCXLV